# Regarding stackify-api, data not displaying in stackify logs

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

Currently, I am using a trial version.When hit from the php code using the monolog and syslog, the logs are displayed in the stackify log management console.But as mentioned in

**https://github.com/stackify/stackify-api/blob/master/endpoints/POST_Log_Save.md**

When I hit using POSTMAN tool, the response I receive is 
    {
      "success": true,
      "took": 46
    }

But the logs are not displayed in the stackify logs console.
My postman request headers:

Content-Type,Accept,X-Stackify-PV,X-Stackify-Key are provided.

Body:

```
{
  "Env": "Prod",
  "ServerName": "rajeshwar-latitude-3450",
  "AppName": "Stackifytest",
  "Msgs": [
    {
      "Msg": "debug message",
      "Level": "DEBUG"
    },
    {
      "Msg": "info message",
      "Level": "DEBUG"
    }
   ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the EpochMs field is required.

Please check the readme file. It says which fields are required.

https://github.com/stackify/stackify-api/blob/master/endpoints/POST_Log_Save.md